# How to dockerize java spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I have a jhipster generated spring boot application, which I want to dockerize and use inside an docker-comopose. I am kind of new to docker, what I did was to copy the app.yml which generated automatically and paste it renaming it to app-dev, there I changed the profile of my application to dev and jhipster registry and eureka url to localhost instead of jhipster. But when I try to start it, jhipster and mysql starts but my application gives the following error:

```
Request execution failed with message: I/O error on POST request for "http://admin:admin@localhost:8761/eureka/apps/MONIESTA_GATEWAY": Connect to localhost:8761 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused); nested exception is org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:8761 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
[nfoReplicator-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_MONIESTA_GATEWAY/moniesta_gateway:46c53f09d6025a0390dd80a03ae1a675 - registration failed Cannot execute request on any known server
```

As far as I understand it, it can not find the eureka server. Can someone tell me what my mistake is, this is how my app-dev yml looks:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  moniesta_gateway-app:
    image: moniesta_gateway
    environment:
      - _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xmx512m -Xms256m
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev,api-docs
      - MANAGEMENT_METRICS_EXPORT_PROMETHEUS_ENABLED=true
      - EUREKA_CLIENT_SERVICE_URL_DEFAULTZONE=http://admin:$${jhipster.registry.password}@jhipster-registry:8761/eureka
      - SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_URI=http://admin:$${jhipster.registry.password}@jhipster-registry:8761/config
      - SPRING_R2DBC_URL=r2dbc:h2:file://tmp/h2db/db/moniesta_gateway?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC&createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
      - SPRING_LIQUIBASE_URL=jdbc:h2:file://tmp/h2db/db/moniesta_gateway?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC&createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
      - JHIPSTER_SLEEP=30 # gives time for other services to boot before the application
    # If you want to expose these ports outside your dev PC,
    # remove the "127.0.0.1:" prefix
    ports:
      - 127.0.0.1:8080:8080
  moniesta_gateway-mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0.27
    # volumes:
    #   - ~/volumes/jhipster/moniesta_gateway/mysql/:/var/lib/mysql/
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=moniesta_gateway
    # If you want to expose these ports outside your dev PC,
    # remove the "127.0.0.1:" prefix
    ports:
      - 127.0.0.1:3306:3306
    command: mysqld --lower_case_table_names=1 --skip-ssl --character_set_server=utf8mb4 --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp
  jhipster-registry:
    image: jhipster/jhipster-registry:v7.2.0
    volumes:
      - ./central-server-config:/central-config
    # When run with the "dev" Spring profile, the JHipster Registry will
    # read the config from the local filesystem (central-server-config directory)
    # When run with the "prod" Spring profile, it will read the configuration from a Git repository
    # See https://www.jhipster.tech/jhipster-registry/#spring-cloud-config
    environment:
      - JHIPSTER_SLEEP=20
      - _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xmx512m -Xms256m
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev,api-docs
      - SPRING_SECURITY_USER_PASSWORD=admin
      - JHIPSTER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD=admin
      - SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_SERVER_COMPOSITE_0_TYPE=native
      - SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_SERVER_COMPOSITE_0_SEARCH_LOCATIONS=file:./central-config/localhost-config/
      # - SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_SERVER_COMPOSITE_0_TYPE=git
      # - SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_SERVER_COMPOSITE_0_URI=https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-registry/
      # - SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_SERVER_COMPOSITE_0_SEARCH_PATHS=central-config
    # If you want to expose these ports outside your dev PC,
    # remove the "127.0.0.1:" prefix
    ports:
      - 127.0.0.1:8761:8761
```

EDIT:

This is the first error message I am gettting but funny thing is, now it says connected to jhipster running in docker. But would that not mean it should be able to connect to eureka?

```
2022-02-27 19:59:27.274  INFO 1 --- [tbeatExecutor-0] c.n.d.s.t.d.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient  : Request execution error. endpoint=DefaultEndpoint{ serviceUrl='http://admin:admin@localhost:8761/eureka/}, exception=I/O error on PUT request for "http://admin:admin@localhost:8761/eureka/apps/MONIESTA_GATEWAY/moniesta_gateway:5fff6b4bfda0f55d8baa193e5732e166": Connect to localhost:8761 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused); nested exception is org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:8761 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused) stacktrace=org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on PUT request for "http://admin:admin@localhost:8761/eureka/apps/MONIESTA_GATEWAY/moniesta_gateway:5fff6b4bfda0f55d8baa193e5732e166": Connect to localhost:8761 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused); nested exception is org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:8761 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)

at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:785)

at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:711)

at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:602)

at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.http.RestTemplateEurekaHttpClient.sendHeartBeat(RestTemplateEurekaHttpClient.java:99)

at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$3.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:92)

at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.executeOnNewServer(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:121)

at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:80)

at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.sendHeartBeat(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:89)

at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$3.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:92)

at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:120)

at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.sendHeartBeat(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:89)

at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$3.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:92)

at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77)

at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.sendHeartBeat(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:89)

at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.renew(DiscoveryClient.java:893)

at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient$HeartbeatThread.run(DiscoveryClient.java:1457)

at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)

at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)

at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)

at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)

at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:8761 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)

at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:156)

at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:376)

at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)

at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)

at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)

at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)

at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)

at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)

at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)

at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)

at org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.java:87)

at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)

at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:66)

at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:109)

at org.springframework.http.client.support.BasicAuthenticationInterceptor.intercept(BasicAuthenticationInterceptor.java:79)

at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:93)

at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:77)

at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)

at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:66)

at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:776)

... 20 more

Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)

at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)

at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)

at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)

at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)

at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)

at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)

at org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:75)

at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)

... 39 more


2022-02-27 19:59:27.275  WARN 1 --- [tbeatExecutor-0] c.n.d.s.t.d.RetryableEurekaHttpClient    : Request execution failed with message: I/O error on PUT request for "http://admin:admin@localhost:8761/eureka/apps/MONIESTA_GATEWAY/moniesta_gateway:5fff6b4bfda0f55d8baa193e5732e166": Connect to localhost:8761 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused); nested exception is org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:8761 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)

2022-02-27 19:59:27.275 ERROR 1 --- [tbeatExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_MONIESTA_GATEWAY/moniesta_gateway:5fff6b4bfda0f55d8baa193e5732e166 - was unable to send heartbeat!
```

Comment: jhipster dockerization is done using JIB to create docker image to use with docker-compose so you dont need to dockerize your self. change localhost back to jhipster-registry and then add 127.0.0.1 jhipster-registry to /etc/hosts . run your docker-compose file again.

Comment: also to create dev yaml you just need to change SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE to dev. and make sure to read https://www.jhipster.tech/docker-compose/#3

Comment: I added to etc hosts jhipster like this: 127.0.0.1 jhipster-registry but it still gives me the same error. I also so there was this line: 127.0.0.1 kubernetes.docker.internal
is this a problem?

Comment: no what /etc/hosts does is just resolves the name to ip

Comment: Ok but it did not help sadly still getting the same error, I update now my yaml for you to see the actual version

Comment: Can you provide your application error because not being able to see eureka wont stop your app to start so there must be somthing else creating problem

Comment: I did updated my post

Comment: Check your localhost:8080 it seems your app hasn’t failed its just service discovery heartbeat error - or you have to print all the log from beginning

Comment: run docker ps in terminal and check which containers are running

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I just looked in docker ps it is shown, but for example I can not use my gateway to authenticate anymore but when I start in intellj it works. Also it is not shown in jhipster registry and I can not login to it in localhost:8080

Comment: this is the error I am getting: Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:8761 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)